# Pass a JSON List for a PUT method in my APEX Web Service

Tags: apex, apexrest

I have written a REST web service with a HttpPut method where it works great (updates the records) if I pass a JSON similar to this:

```
{
  "ticketName" : "INC0611231",
  "Status" : "Closed",
  "workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!" 
}
```

However, I am trying to pass a list of JSON so that a list of records can get updated in one transaction instead of passing a json repsonse 1 at a time like above. In other words I am trying to pass this:

```
{
      "ticketName" : "INC0611xyz",
      "Status" : "Closed",
      "workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!" 
    },
{
      "ticketName" : "INC0611tze",
      "Status" : "Closed",
      "workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!" 
    },
{
      "ticketName" : "INC061165t",
      "Status" : "Closed",
      "workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!" 
    }
```

My current code is below:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/tickets/*')
global class CC_MyService {
@HttpPut
    global static List<Ticket__c> UpdateTicket(String ticketName, String Status, String workNotes){
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        
        
        List<Ticket__c> Ticket = new List<Ticket__c>();
        List<Ticket__c> TicketUpdate = new List<Ticket__c>();
        
        if(ticketName <> null){
            Ticket = [SELECT Id, Name, Status__c FROM Ticket__c WHERE Name =:ticketName];   
        }
        
        if(Ticket.size() != null){
            for(Ticket__c snow : Ticket){
                snow.Name = ticketName;
                snow.Status__c = Status;
                snow.Comments_and_Work_Notes__c = workNotes;
                TicketUpdate.add(snow);
            }
            try{
                upsert TicketUpdate;  
            }
            catch(DMLException e) {
                system.debug('***************************************** ' + e.getMessage()); 
                system.debug('***************************************** ' + e.getStackTraceString());
            } 
            
        }
        
        return TicketUpdate;
    }
```

Can some one please help me o how I could convert my current code so that it takes a list instead of single parameter so that it process a JSON list like I showed? Thank you so much

Comment: You may want to create a wrapper object and put the list of wrapper records as input parameter
global static List<Ticket__c> UpdateTicket(List<WrapperClass> wrapperList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper Apex class as shown below:

```
Public class TicketWrapper{
    String ticketName;
    String Status;
    String workNotes;
}
```

Your JSON should be in the following format (note the `square braces` since you are sending a list or array):

```
[
    {"ticketName" : "INC0611xyz", "Status" : "Closed", "workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"},
    {"ticketName" : "INC0611tze","Status" : "Closed","workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"},
    {"ticketName" : "INC061165t","Status" : "Closed","workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"}
]
```

In your REST service apex, change the method signature as follows:

```
global static List<Ticket__c> UpdateTicket(String jsonString)
```

And, you can use the following code to deserialize the JSON string and ***update the code as shown below***:

```
List<TicketWrapper> ltw = (List<TicketWrapper>)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, List<TicketWrapper>.class);

List<String> ticketNames = new List<String>();
Map<String, TicketWrapper> ticketMap = new Map<String, TicketWrapper>();
for(TicketWrapper tw: ltw){
    ticketNames.add(tw.ticketName); 
    ticketMap.put(tw.ticketName, tw);
}

List<Ticket__c> ticketList = [SELECT Id, Name, Status__c FROM Ticket__c WHERE Name =:ticketNames];
List<Ticket__c> TicketUpdate = new List<Ticket__c>();
if(ticketList.size() > 0){
    for(Ticket__c ticket: ticketList){
        TicketWrapper tw = ticketMap.get(ticket.Name);
        ticket.Name = tw.ticketName;
        ticket.Status__c = tw.Status;
        ticket.Comments_and_Work_Notes__c = tw.workNotes;
        TicketUpdate.add(ticket);
    }
    
    try{
        upsert TicketUpdate;  
    }
    catch(DMLException e) {
        system.debug('***************************************** ' + e.getMessage()); 
        system.debug('***************************************** ' + e.getStackTraceString());
    }   
}
```

Comment: What do I do after the deserialize line of code? would this hit DML limits? How would I change the SOQL query to accomodate ltw?

Comment: You can update the code to accommodate bulkification. See sample code updated in the answer.

Comment: (not specifically for this use case) but, Is it possible to accept 'generic' JSON and then parse it?